# Google Mini Search Appliance

Tags: google, search

HI All,

A friend of mine has a Google Mini-0020 3GHz Search Appliance that he said I can have. I have heard about these, but never put one into production.

What kinds of things can I do with it? (obviously I know about search and indexing documents) but i mean it is standard PC hardware.

Is there an OS on it? (Like Windows Server?)

I assume that I could nuke it and make it into anything I wanted.

Could I do more with it and retain the Google search? Like host my complete website on the box?

Thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can't host other services on the machine. Essentially if you want to do anything except use it as a search appliance you'll have to wipe it and in that process you'll lose the search capabilities.

Comment: @Josh - Got it. I can obviously replace the hard drive and keep the original in tact. So what do they have on it for an OS?

Comment: Also,  You void your warranty by modifying the appliance in any way, making you ineligible for technical support, should you break things.

Comment: @Joe - It is not under warranty I believe which they bought new one recently. Weird that every two years you have to buy a complete new box

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an OS on it? (Like Windows
>   Server?)

Yes, is a linux box with some kind of CentOS

> I assume that I could nuke it and make
>   it into anything I wanted.

No, there is a root user but only Google has access via ssh. The user can manage the equipment and update the software through a web interface.

> Could I do more with it and retain the
>   Google search? Like host my complete
>   website on the box?

There are some templates to present results in the GSA, so you can host a web page, but is not intended for that.

Comment: CentOS?! I've heard some rumors saying that Google uses Ubuntu, but nothing about RHEL or something else based on it.